# Are there any analogues in the standard library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found that I pretty often use the following logic:

1. Do some action for some `value`;
2. Take next `x` from the sequence;
3. Modify the `value` with `x` somehow;
4. Do the same action for resulted value;
5. Go to step 2 while sequence is not empty.

For example, `value` could be a 2d point and the sequence could contain 2d vectors.

I've written a simple function for that, but I am curious about the analogues in the standard library. It looks like the pretty common scenario for me, but I didn't find anything in `itertools` so far.

```
def iter_transform(value, sequence, transform):
    yield value
    for v in sequence:
        value = transform(value, v)
        yield value

print(list(iter_transform(10, [+3, +4, -7, -5], lambda x, y: x + y)))
```

Output:

```
[10, 13, 17, 10, 5]
```

**UPDATE**

It's not always trivial to add the value itself to the list. Of course, when we are talking about numbers or coordinates, there is always a `zero`, and the transformation is something arifthmetic.

But even types of `value` and `x` could be different:

```
print(list(iter_transform('values:', [+3, +4, -7, -5], lambda x, y: x + ' ' + str(y))))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['values:', 'values: 3', 'values: 3 4', 'values: 3 4 -7', 'values: 3 4 -7 -5']
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `itertools.accumulate()` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate

Comment: The only difference between `accumulate` and `iter_transform` is that `accumulate` doesn't take an explicit initial value. You can fix that by simply prepending that to your sequence: `accumulate(['values'] + [3, 4, -7, -5], lambda x, y: x+ ' ' + str(y))`.

Comment: list concatenation in that was is `O(n)`, isn't it?

Comment: It is, but so is `lambda x, y: x + y` in this case. You could use `itertools.chain` instead of creating a new list. (`chain(['values'], [3, 4, -7, -5])`).

Comment: I like that much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution by combining the built-in `reduce()` function and list comprehension:

```
In [1]: l = [+3, +4, -7, -5]

In [2]: [reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l[:i+1]) for i in range(len(l), 10)]
Out[2]: [10, 13, 17, 10, 5]
```

But this is not very effective, because the reduce function is doing too much repeated caculations.

---

UPDATE: Another solution with reduce(), more effective but less straightforward.

```
In [1]: l = [+3, +4, -7, -5]

In [2]: result = [l[0]]

In [3]: reduce(lambda x, y: result.append(x + y) or (x + y), l, 10)
Out[3]: 5

In [4]: result
Out[4]: [10, 13, 17, 10, 5]
```

Comment: You are missing the initial condition that `10` is not in the transformation list. Adding it to the beginning of the sequence is not even always possible when values are not plain numbers

Comment: But in my option `reduce()` meets your requirement anyway, the "forloop" part of your code is typical reduce-like.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But are you sure it's better/more readable/faster?

Comment: To me, your `iter_transform` function is simple and good enough. I posted this "reduce() solution" only to give you some different thoughts, not to mean it's better/faster. :)